# Receiving database error when using find_or_initialize_by_ticker

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running an association find_or_initialize_by_ticker method and keep receiving

```
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted,
commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

My position has a stock_id attribute and I want to check whether or not a particular stock object exists for any of my positions.

If a stock object already exists, then I can grab it and if not a new position will be created and I can use that object.

I was thinking of writing my own method with an association extension like

```
has_many :positions do
  def find_or_initialize_by_ticker(ticker)
    position_with_ticker = self.select do |position|
      position.stock['symbol'] == ticker
    end
    if position_with_ticker
      position_with_ticker.first
    else
      Position.new
    end
  end
end
```

Is this the most efficient way to find a position?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use ActiveRecord's built-in [`#first_or_initialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize)?

It's already built for you, and it's much faster to do the filtering on the database rather than returning all rows and then filtering them manually with `select` (much less data to transfer).

How you'd use it depends on how you've defined the `stock` variable:

#### Stock is another table

```
my_model.positions
        .joins(:stock)
        .where(stock: { symbol: ticker })
        .first_or_initialize
```

#### Stock is a Postgres JSON or HSTORE field

From [Active Record and PostgreSQL](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json):

```
# see docs for -> vs ->>
my_model.positions
        .where("stock->>'symbol' = ?", ticker)
        .first_or_initialize
```